# Find vertices in .obj File which were marked in Blender

Tags: materials, objects, vertices, file-format, vertex-groups

I am searching for a way to somehow be able to select specific vertices of an object in Blender and I want to find the same vertices in the exported .obj file. I would like to group those vertices in the .obj file.

Are there any ideas how I could do that? Maybe over a material definition for the selected vertices? Or is there a possibility to group vertices in Blender and exporting those group information into the obj file?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you've decided against separating those vertices so you only export each part separately, i.e. two individual obj files?

(Delete the section(s) you don't want to include in the first obj file, export what's left, then reload the Blender file, delete the other section and export that for the second obj file.

When both are imported their scaling and relative positions should still match so it's easy to recombine/join them (CTL-J) when imported back into Blender)

Comment: Thank you for your response! My issue was that I did not know how to find the seperated vertices in the exported obj file but I found out now that I had to check "Objects as OBJ Objects" when exporting. This writes the object name above the belonging vertices in the obj file.
Thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: You're most welcome.   Thanks to your reply, I too have learned something valuable!  :)   For me Blender is a never ending world of discovery!